# No match for operator QDataStream operator>> for QJsonObject on MacOS

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I would like to use QDataStream to read from a file and load it into a QJsonObject, but I get the following error on macOS:

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('QDataStream' and 'QJsonObject')

even though the QJsonObject has an overloaded operator>> for QDataStream:
[image]

The relevant code snippet:

```
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QDir>
#include <QFile>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QTime>


std::vector<JsonDataTypes::JsonRecords> FileCacheHandler::readLogs()
{
    std::vector<JsonDataTypes::JsonRecords> returnRecords;

    QFile cacheFile(SubFolderName + QStringLiteral("/%1").arg(cacheFileName));

    if (!cacheFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        qWarning(FileCacheManagerLog) << "Couldn't open cache file with name:" << cacheFileName;
        return{};
    }

    QDataStream in(&cacheFile);
    
    while (!in.atEnd()) {
        QJsonObject record;
        in >> record;   #<<<<<<--- Issue occurs here, error: Invalid operands to binary expression ('QDataStream' and 'QJsonObject')
        returnRecords.emplace_back(record);
    }

    cacheFile.close();
    return returnRecords;
}
```

In the cmake file I am including all necessary packages:

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Network REQUIRED)
```

Comment: I am compiling for windows and mac too, and on windows it does not have any issue, also on windows I can jump to the definition to this operator>>, so I would expect it should work on macOS too.

Comment: Maybe you have different Qt version on macOS? Which one?

Comment: @vahancho Hmmm, 5.15.4 on windows, 5.12.11 on MacOs

Comment: That explains the problem. It looks like 5.12.x doesn't have these overloads yet.

Comment: There is a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61924590/no-match-for-operator-operand-types-are-qdatastream-and-qjsonobject